# gmap.draw TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python-3.x, typeerror, python-3.6, heatmap

i'm trying to plot a heat map using the gmplot package:

```
import gmplot

gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter.from_geocode("Los Angeles",10)

gmap.heatmap(lat_lon['latitude'], lat_lon['longitude'])

gmap.draw('crime_map.html')
```

however the `gmap.draw` statement throws the next error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not str
```

i'm not getting at all why it's yelling this, my latitude and longitude columns have float dtypes:

```
lat_lon.dtypes
```

> ```
> latitude     float64
> longitude    float64
> dtype: object
> ```

Any ideas about why is this happening??

thanks in advance for the help :)